# .js Async issues.. SQL command is Posting before making changes

Tags: javascript, mysql

so I have a function that is fetching data from mySQL and inserting it into a list(emptyList). It then should insert that filled list to mySQL, which is done in the storeSQL() function. But when ran, it stores the array with none of the new data inserted? It should call storeSQL after the gatherEmptyValueHelper method is completed for the last time. Does anyone know why this is happening?

```
async function populateEmptyList(message) {
Object.keys(theDataArray).forEach(function(key) {
    //console.log(key, dictionary[key]);
    if (theDataArray[key] == null) {
        emptyList.push(emptyListIndex[key])
    }
});
if (emptyList.length != 0) {
    let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        for (i = 0; i < emptyList.length; i++) {
            gatherEmptyValueHelper(emptyList[i], function(message, category, result) {
                testdata(category, result);
                gatheredList[category] = result;
                if (gatheredList.length == emptyList.length) {
                    resolve(1)
                }
            });

        }
    });

    let result = await promise;
    storeSQL()


} else {
    console.log("NOPE")
}
```

}

Comment: Where is "await yourFetchDataFunction()" ? You don't wait for anything. What is emptyListIndex? Why do you push data from it, if theDataArray[key] is null?

Comment: I have updated the code above, and emptyListIndex is just to grab the categories for my database, and that category gets pushed to my emptyList if the value was null. And for every value that I have pushed to my empty list, I would want to run the gatherEmptyValueHelper

Comment: var emptyListIndex = {"time":"dateTime","casetemp":"bbCaseTemp",..}

Comment: But you're not waiting for the function that fetches data. You don't have "await fetchData()" function.

Comment: Is "let result = await promise" not waiting for the Promise to resolve? I'm trying to use a structure similar to this:

Comment: async function f() {

  let promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("done!"), 1000)
  });

  let result = await promise; // wait until the promise resolves (*)

  alert(result); // "done!"
}

f();

Comment: Which part of that function does fetch data? I don't see API requests, Axios or fetch() etc.

Comment: gatherEmptyValueHelper fetches the data from my database: function gatherEmptyValueHelper(category, callback) {

        var mysql      = require('mysql');
        var connection = mysql.createConnection({